# Overlapping highcharts and renderer in different divs

Tags: highcharts, renderer

I wanted to overlap highchart and renderer in two different divs in a html but could not do it.

I tried the z-index for the div and the chart/renderer, didn't work.

I tried drawing in the sequence I wanted the overlapping to be, didn't work.

Cannot use absolute position for the div I want to place on top of all other divs.

Am I missing something?. This is my code

```
<style>.style1 {
    height: 300px;    width:200px;    float:left;
    border: 1px solid red;    background-color: yellow;
    z-index:3;
}
.style2 {
    height: 200px;    width: 200px;    float:left;
    border: 1px solid black;    background-color: red;
    margin-left:-50px;
    z-index:3;
}
.style3 {
    height: 200px;    width: 200px;    float:left;
    border: 1px solid black;    background-color: orange;
    z-index:0; margin-left:-90px;
}</style>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="style1"></div>
<div id="container2" class="style2"></div>
<div id="container3" class="style3"></div>

$(function () {
    var renderer = new Highcharts.Renderer(
    $('#container')[0],
    200,
    200);

    renderer.rect(10, 10, 100, 50, 5).attr({
        fill: 'blue',
        stroke: 'black',
            'stroke-width': 1
    }).add();

    renderer.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
            'stroke-width': 1
    }).add();


    drawChart1();
    drawChart2();
    //renderer.toFront();
});


function drawChart1() {
    c = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2',
            borderWidth:1,borderRadius:0,
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart 1'
        },

        series: [{
            data: [1, 2, 3]
        }]
    });
};

function drawChart2() {
    c = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container3',
            borderWidth:1,borderRadius:0,
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart 2'
        },

        series: [{
            data: [1, 2, 3]
        }]
    });
};
```

I have created a  [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vijaykdotcom/Z7Vg2/)

Comment: So charts should be "above" yellow box, or how it should looks like? Have any any image with concept?

Comment: I cannot add any image on the forum yet (dont have enough reputation). The yellow box should be above charts. I am rendering a small box(with dynamic data) that overlaps on the chart to some extent. This small box will appear based on some conditions and cannot be included within the chart area as it is dependent on the rest of the html page but not on the chart. Any ideas to implement are also welcome.